# how to deal with big picture in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a big picture to show in UIScrollView.It's 28.1 MB.And it often crash the app.Is there some methods to deal with it so that app won't crash?

Comment: Yes.  Compress your image to a more suitable image format. What type of image are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static PNG image, run it through ImageAlpha and ImageOptim (Google these). You might be able to get it down by well over 50%. Bundle the resulting image with your app instead.

Note that ImageOptim is lossless whereas ImageAlpha is lossy. You can use them in conjunction.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go buddy,

[Convert Large Image to tiles](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/10/cutting-large-images-into-tiles-for.html)

Displaying tiled images in UIScrollview

[Tiled Images in UIScrollView](https://github.com/soleilpqd/UIScrollView-infinity-and-tile-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Split up the image and load the pieces only when necessary.